# Is 3x3x2x2 ANOVA possible?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anova, sas

I just don’t want to look dumb suggesting it. I have 4 categorical IVs with a continuous DV. Two IVs with 3 levels and two with two levels. Am I right to start off by testing via ANOVA assuming the assumptions are met? Then moving onto post hoc tests

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Absolutely. But a more important question is: does this analysis make sense for your study? Are you expecting all four variables to meaningfully interact with one-another to produce variation in the outcome variable? Also, another thing to consider is the amount of statistical power you will have to detect such complex, higher-order interactions with your given sample size.